# jackson parsing javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, json, parsing, jackson

Is it possible to parse a JSON string containing a Javascript function into a Jackson JsonNode ?

The (JSON formatted) string I try to parse :

```
{
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
    "key3" : function () {
       // some javascript code
    }
}
```

In a Java object, I would expect something like a Map (Javascript function converted to String).

Currently, I have the following exception :

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'function'
```

I found lots of features for non-valid JSON use but still not what I would like ...

Any idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear from your description but the string you show cannot be "JSON-formatted" if it has a function unless the function itself is represented as a string like `"function () {}"`. (JSON does not allow functions--not sure from your description that you are clear on that or not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not valid JSON, and it is not supported by Jackson; nor is it likely to be supported in future. I would suggest making that a regular JSON String, and then re-parsing on Javascript side if and as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

JSON doesn't allow functions. It is meant for safe data-transfer though you could encode the function as a string like this:

```
{
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
    "key3" : "function () { ... }"
}
```

...but upon re-encoding, it would be a string rather than a function unless you were to `eval()` it (though that could well be unsafe).

Comment: Thanks Brett. It's a little hard to explain but I try ! :-)
Actually, I use Jackson to generate JSON formatted String (from Java objects and from file containing JSON like the example above) and finally build Javascript content, server side.
The generated Javascript is then written in a HTTPResponse and interpreted client-side.
So, I think I cannot encode the function as a String, whereas I need to be "seen" as a String :-/
Maybe with a custom parser ?